# Problem getting certain details from google API JSON result in react native

Tags: arrays, json, react-native, google-maps-api-3

I have having problems getting the just the city name from the result of an API call to google maps. I have put what I have tried below the result.

I get the results like so(sorry its long!) :-

```
{"plus_code": {"compound_code": "CF7P+FPG Coventry, UK", "global_code": "9C4WCF7P+FPG"}, "results": [{"address_components": [Array], 
"formatted_address": "Samuel Vale House, St Nicholas St, Coventry CV1 4LU, UK", "geometry": [Object], "place_id": "ChIJwZLlz6JLd0gReeZG93iyO84", "types": [Array]}, {"address_components": [Array], "formatted_address": "28 Draper's Fields, Coventry CV1 4RB, UK", "geometry": [Object], "place_id": "ChIJledqNL1Ld0gRopKXZBQ3Dbw", "plus_code": [Object], "types": [Array]}, {"address_components": [Array], "formatted_address": "St Nicholas St, Coventry CV1, UK", "geometry": [Object], "place_id": "ChIJLcZB06JLd0gRJH9Mq01bnb0", "types": [Array]}, {"address_components": [Array], "formatted_address": "CF7P+FP Coventry, UK", "geometry": [Object], "place_id": "GhIJ4m1KHvQ0SkAReZvtwO81-L8", "plus_code": [Object], "types": [Array]}, {"address_components": [Array], "formatted_address": "25 Draper's Fields, Coventry CV1, UK", "geometry": [Object], "place_id": "EiAyNSBEcmFwZXIncyBGaWVsZHMsIENvdmVudHJ5LCBVSyIaEhgKFAoSCXHOkje9S3dIEaN9YbIkhsbsEBk", "types": [Array]}, {"address_components": [Array], "formatted_address": "Coventry CV1 4AF, UK", "geometry": [Object], "place_id": "ChIJL_gRNr1Ld0gR-C3zVwB43JE", "types": [Array]}, {"address_components": [Array], "formatted_address": "Coventry CV1, UK", "geometry": [Object], "place_id": "ChIJFXaeGQhLd0gRXmNKR5ZDV9Y", "types": [Array]}, {"address_components": [Array], "formatted_address": "Coventry, UK", "geometry": [Object], "place_id": "ChIJtyJuZVGxcEgRiQZPVvVg9gQ", "types": [Array]}, {"address_components": [Array], "formatted_address": "Coventry, UK", "geometry": [Object], "place_id": "ChIJc1uq9aFLd0gRIImX1COLDQQ", "types": [Array]}, {"address_components": [Array], "formatted_address": "Coventry, UK", "geometry": [Object], "place_id": "ChIJzyd10oVLd0gR7LyimJZGazw", "types": [Array]}, {"address_components": [Array], "formatted_address": "West Midlands, UK", "geometry": [Object], "place_id": "ChIJ_dclMtSAcEgR5_O7OttvyI0", "types": [Array]}, {"address_components": [Array], "formatted_address": 
"England, UK", "geometry": [Object], "place_id": "ChIJ39UebIqp0EcRqI4tMyWV4fQ", "types": [Array]}, {"address_components": [Array], "formatted_address": "United Kingdom", "geometry": [Object], "place_id": "ChIJqZHHQhE7WgIReiWIMkOg-MQ", "types": [Array]}], "status": "OK"}
```

I call the API like so :-

```
axios({
  method: 'get',
  url: 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?&key={my_key}&latlng='+latitude+','+longitude
}).then((response) => {
  console.log(response.data);
});
```

I have played with everything but I simply can not do it. I think its something to do with using map but I am not sure. If so, how do I use it? The closest I can get to breaking it down is :

```
console.log(response.data.results[0].address_components[0].long_name)
```

I can achieve this within a normal javascript within a webpage like this but it does not work within react native

```
$.each( data['results'],function(i, val) {
                $.each( val['address_components'],function(i, val) {
                    if (val['types'] == "locality,political") {
                        if (val['long_name']!="") {
                            var city = val['long_name']; // Getting the city name
                        }
                        else {
                           // UNKNOWN
                        }
```

Answer (score 0):

After lots of playing around, I have managed to do it. Code below in case anyone else has the same problem. I also found this site which makes it quite easy to view JSON in more readable format.

https://jsonviewer.stack.hu/

```
console.log(response.data.results[7].formatted_address)
```